# Having trouble with Hough Transform in C

Tags: c, image, image-processing, sdl, hough-transform

I am trying to make a code that detects sudoku grids. This means that I have to apply lots of filters on the image and then apply the Hough Transform algorithm on it following the output of Sobel algorithm (which makes the edges appear as white pixels on a black image).

I somewhat understand its concept and why it is important to use `Rho = x*cos(Theta) + y*sin(Theta)` to obtain the edges coordinates in a parameter space.

However, I'm having issues with Rho and my accumulator array.
Here is my code so far:

```
void hough(SDL_Surface* image_surface)
{

    unsigned int width = image_surface->w;
    unsigned int height = image_surface->h;
    
    unsigned int Rhos, Thetas;
    Rhos = sqrt(width * width + height * height);
    Thetas = 180;

    //initialise accumulator array
    unsigned int acc_array[Rhos][Thetas];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Rhos; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Thetas; j++)
            acc_array[i][j] = 0;
    }
    Uint32 pixel;
    Uint8 r, g, b;

    //go through each pixels
    for (size_t x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (size_t y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            pixel = get_pixel(image_surface, x, y);
            SDL_GetRGB(pixel, image_surface->format, &r, &g, &b);
                  
            //if white
            if (r+g+b == 765)
            {
                //p = x*cos(t) + y*sin(t)
                //check for every t
                for (int t = 0; t < 180;t++)
                {
                    unsigned int p = x*cos(t) + y*sin(t);
                    acc_array[p][t]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

//rest of the code below...
```

My problem is that when, for example, I am on the pixel (20, 1882) of the image and my theta (or t) = 4, p (or Rho) becomes -1437.
If Rho is negative, then I cannot increment its place in the accumulator array since an index cannot be negative.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: There are components in your sample code that do not include definitions, i.e. the struct argument `SDL_Surface`, input values, expected outputs, etc.  Please edit to include a scaled down usage example, that is compileable, that also causes the problem to occur.  ( [mcve] )

Comment: Why does `p` need to be an index? Why can’t you transform it linearly into an index?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The hough transform algorithms I see online all have an accumulator array with p and theta.
Sorry, I'm a bit new to C code.

Answer (score 1):

The cos() and sin() functions expect the angle to be in radians. Based on your for loop range it looks t is a value in degrees.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
However, how would you suggest I go about the t in the accumulator array?
It currently has [p][t].

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go through 180 degrees, just 90. The negative is coming from thetas > 90.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).